# How to retrieve the last created object from Firebase Database on server side

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to Firebase cloud functions so sorry if this is pretty straight forward. I'm trying to receive the latest pushed object in my database. Unfortunately this code returns every object that already was pushed in the database at '/customers'. I already tried .onCreate but that didn't do anything at all.

```
exports.newCustomer = functions.database.ref('/customers/').onWrite(event => {
  console.log(event.data.val());
});
```

[image]

Comment: Please include the JSON data structure on the post?

Comment: @UmarZaii Added the data structure

Comment: @Thore I edited my answer so you can capture your data easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That onWrite event should only capture new data. However maybe you should more specific like this:

```
exports.newCustomer = functions.database.ref('/customers/{randomID}').onWrite(event => {
  console.log(event.data.val()); //here is the data that is added
  console.log(event.params.randomID); // random ID
  console.log(event.data.val().firstName); //change firstName to anything you added.
});
```

This will capture any write event to /customers/XXX/XXX/

Comment: Just to be sure. Are {randomID} and {values} placeholders for every possible value?

Comment: @Thore yes, this is special from Firebase I think ( I do not work with Javascript besides Firebase). Enter anything in that url and get the values with the event.params :D

Comment: Also see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#specify_the_path

Comment: @J.Doe So I checked your methode and the first console.log ( console.log(event.data.val()); ) is only returning the email of the latest entry.

Comment: @Thore What do the other logs say? I think the last one is the most important, change enterkeyhere to firstName and you will see the value for that key.

Comment: @J.Doe Maybe it is because in my database rules I added indexOn: email for /customers (will check this in a minute)

Comment: @Thore Nah, if the values are added together, the onWrite event should capture everything. Check the last log like I said before here, changing that key.

Comment: @J.Doe I'm getting errors on all the functions with event.params.xxxx.xxx

For example, the last one were I changed enterkeyhere to firstName:


`console.log(event.params.values.val().firstName);`

Gives me these errors



`TypeError: event.params.values.val is not a function
    at exports.newCustomer.functions.database.ref.onWrite.event (/user_code/index.js:38:35)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:35:20
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)`

Comment: @Thore I made a mistake. Can you check out the new code?

Comment: @J.Doe I think there is still something wrong. I tested your new code and here are the results:

`console.log(event.params.randomID);` is perfectly working.
`console.log(event.data.val());` is was expecting an object with all the data but it's logging 3 times (every key gets his own log instead of one log with the complete object)
`console.log(event.data.val().firstName);` This is the strangest one. It's logging 'undefined' 3 times

Comment: @Thore hmmm... 1 last try: remove the '/{values}' in the URL

Comment: @J.Doe Just tried that and that was the solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Thore Yes finally :D please accept this answer! Good luck